# Android Gradle plugin update to v2.3.0 breaks Copy task

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have the following task in my Android build.gradle file which copies my built APK file for me:

```
/**
 * Copies the final release APK into the project root folder.
 */
task copyRelease(type: Copy) {
    // define output files exactly to work around a file locking issue
    outputs.files.setFrom(file("../app-release.apk"))

    from "build/outputs/apk/app-release.apk"
    into ".."
}
```

This has been working for a long time and broke today when doing Android Studio's suggested update:

- Android Gradle plugin v2.3.0 (from v2.2.3)
- Gradle v3.3 (from v2.14.1)

Running the Grade build now gives the following error on the line `outputs.files.setfrom(...)`:

```
No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskOutputs$TaskOutputUnionFileCollection.setFrom() is applicable for argument types: (java.io.File) values: [..\app-release.apk]
Possible solutions: sort()
```

To summarise, it seems like `TaskOutputUnionFileCollection.setFrom()` no longer takes `File` parameters.

But I do not know how to migrate this code to the new version and a [look through the source class](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/tasks/DefaultTaskOutputs.java) has not helped me.

---

I have looked at the [Android Gradle plugin Known Issues page](https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues.html) as well as the [Gradle 3.3. Release Notes](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/release-notes.html), and found no direct reference to this.

Comment: The "file locking issue" that forces the breaking line is similar to that [detailed in this link](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/build-failure-with-failed-to-capture-snapshot-of-input-files-for-task-war-during-up-to-date-check/9132/8). The root folder of the project contains the `.gradle` folder.

Comment: I have also run into this issue and can't find a mention of it in any docs. Have you been able to find a workaround?

Comment: @user1088166 I've added the workaround that I ended up using. Does what I need but if you find a better solution feel free to post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a direct & exact translation of the above code without implementing a workaround. The problem lies in using the root folder of the project for the destination of the copy command.

The workaround was to create a separate folder `..\release` and then the following code works fine:

```
/**
 * Copies the final release APK into the project root folder.
 */
task copyRelease(type: Copy) {
    from "build/outputs/apk"
    into "../release"
    include "app-release.apk"
}
```